# The type or namespace name 'Column' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple here.
I'm trying to follow a Code First Entity Framework tutorial which tells me to use some Data Annotations.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Model
{
    public class Destination
    {
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName="image")]
        public byte Photo { get; set; }

        public List<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't have any issues with the first two annotations but it doesn't seem to like: `[Column(TypeName="image")]`.

Errors:

- The type or namespace name 'Column' could not be found.
- The type or namespace name 'ColumnAttribute' could not be found.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and Entity Frameworks 5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the photo property must be a byte-array instead of a byte.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In **Entity Framework 4.3.1**, `ColumnAttribute` is defined in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namspace , which is available in `EntityFramework.dll`. So if you have a reference to that dll and a using statement to the namespace, you should be fine.

In **Entity Framework 5**, It is in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` namspace, So you need to add a reference to that in your class.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

You can read more detailed information about it [here](http://techiesweb.net/2012/10/06/column-attribute-in-entity-framework-5.html).

Comment: After adding the reference, I had to do a full clean and rebuild.  Just rebuilding didn't work.

Comment: Your fix worked for me, but the link above appears broken.

Comment: @RussellH Thanks ! Fixed the broken link

Comment: This stays true for EF 6.* too.

Comment: Don't forget to add a reference for `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` if you still have trouble

Answer (score 1):

### I had the correct `using` statements ...

I had this problem despite having the correct `using` statements.

In my case, my project was generated by dotPeek after decompiling a dll (the original source code was lost).

dotPeek created the project with a reference to a copy of EntityFramework.dll just sitting in some folder, not being managed by NuGet.

What worked for me was to remove the reference to EntityFramework, and re-add it using the NuGet console.